# netbeans java.security.cert.certificateexpiredexception

Tags: ssl, netbeans

Hostgator provides free Let's Encrypt SSL cert so I let my Comodo cert expire.  Netbeans won't connect now and gives java.security.cert.certificateexpiredexception.

I'm in the process of renewing the comodo cert but wonder if there is a way to fix this.  The plugin SSL Cert Exception in Netbeans did not fix this issue for me.

Netbeans does not want to connect to remote server because the comodo certificate expired.  I get this error in the popup:

java.security.cert.certificateexpiredexception

It is not recognizing the Let's Encrypt certificate which is still valid that is also on the server.

Comment: Netbean doesn't have anything to do with SSL. Please clarify.

Comment: I think what I wrote is pretty clear.  Netbeans will not connect to my remote server because of the expired comodo certificate.  What exactly is unclear about that to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This SSL issue did not go away when the new comodo cert was installed.  But I was able to use FTP in Netbeans without TLS.

SSL issues appear to have been caching related, Hostgator have since cleared any applicable cache and issues with connecting via FTP on TLS have stopped.

I probably did not need to buy the new comodo cert to fix this issue. Sorry I don't have info on exactly which cache was cleared on the server, but maybe this is enough info to get someone who runs into this issue onto the right path.